# Que es la capacidad de un Slicen o Make en go

Tags: go

como les va? Disculpen las molestias.

La pregunta es, ¿Que es la capacidad de un Slice o Make en Go?

Arranque a estudiar Go y tal vez esta pregunta sea una pavada, pero no entiendo que viene a representar la capacidad, porque el tamaño lo va a designar la longitud del array, para que necesitaría una capacidad entonces?

Me lo estoy imaginando como si la capacidad fuera el tamaño del valor a ingresar, pero se que tampoco es asi. Un ejemplo de esto es decir que tengo una variable con capacidad 1 entonces el valor máximo a ingresar no puede superar a 1.

Por otra parte en el ejemplo de código que se encuentra abajo, me confunde mucho mas porque al principio tiene una capacidad de 2 y luego cuando le asigno otro valor con la función append() cambia de capacidad 2 a 4
Entonces puede también que la capacidad sea el espacio de memoria designado para este tipo de array, pero para eso no existe ya la longitud?

```
func main() {

    meses := []string{"Enero", "Febrero"}

    fmt.Printf("Longitud: %v, Capacidad %v, Referencias %v \n", len(meses), cap(meses), meses)

    meses = append(meses, "Abril")

    fmt.Printf("Longitud: %v, Capacidad %v, Referencias %v \n", len(meses), cap(meses), meses)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Matias espero serte de ayuda.

En Go, los Arrays tienen un tamaño fijo. El tamaño es incluso parte de la definición de un Array, por lo que los dos Arrays [10]int y [20]int no son solo dos Arrays int de diferente tamaño sino que, de hecho, son de diferentes tipos.

A partir de esto podemos intentar entender como funciona un Slice en Go.

Un Slice es una "ventana" a un Array que se compone de 3 cosas.

- Puntero: el puntero se utiliza para apuntar al primer elemento del Array al que se puede acceder a través del slice.
- Longitud: La longitud es el número total de elementos presentes en el Array.
- Capacidad: La capacidad representa el tamaño máximo del Array.

Cuando tu estas haciendo :

```
meses := []string{"Enero", "Febrero"}
```

Estás definiendo un slice y no un Array el cual sería del tipo :

```
meses := [2]string{"Enero", "Febrero"}
```

El tamaño del slice es "dinámico" y cuando queremos agregar algo que excede la capacidad, la capacidad se incrementa a 4 y la longitud se incrementa a 3, en este caso tenemos 3 elementos en el Array y el tamaño máximo hasta el momento es 4.

Tener en cuenta que esta operación tiene un costo asociado ya que es posible que se cambie la referencia al primer elemento del Array y se tengan que mover todos los elementos a otro lugar de memoria donde exista el espacio para almacenar el nuevo Array.